# XSLT - Output in Text without XML Tags

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have used 2 xslt to generate the Output Expected but I am getting the Output where in child elements are clubbed and provided as a text .

So , Can you please let me know on

1) What can be added  at  in XSLT 2 to generate the required output .
 2) Ways to combine 2 xslt and present it as a single xslt .
 3) Better way of writing xslt to generate the output needed.

Details

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:fnsetEngineReleased xmlns:ns1="http://from_sap.interfaces.oms"><ns1:strPO>DDDD</ns1:strPO><ns1:strEngine>ASAS</ns1:strEngine></ns1:fnsetEngineReleased>
```

Output Expected

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:from="http://from_sap.interfaces.oms"> 
  <soap:Header/> 
  <soap:Body> 
     <from:fnsetEngineReleased> 
        <from:strPO>DDDD</from:strPO> 
        <from:strEngine>ASAS</from:strEngine> 
     </from:fnsetEngineReleased> 
  </soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>
```

Output Obtained

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
               xmlns:from="http://from_sap.interfaces.oms">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <from:fnsetEngineReleased>DDDDASAS</from:fnsetEngineReleased>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XSLT1  -Remove Namespace

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT2  -Add Namespace

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:template match="/*">
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  xmlns:from="http://from_sap.interfaces.oms" > 
<soap:Header></soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
            <xsl:element name="from:{local-name()}" namespace="http://from_sap.interfaces.oms">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
         </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both namespaces are the same.  You do not need anything fancy, just copy the input to the output, all you want is wrapping it into a SOAP envelope:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <soap:Envelope> 
         <soap:Header/>
         <soap:Body>
            <xsl:copy-of name="*"/>
         </soap:Body>
      </soap:Envelope>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```